# Load Apache Spark Dataset<Row> to DynamoDB Table using Java

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb

our application creates parquet file and we need to load this data to DynamoDB. I am not finding any Java examples using emr-dynamodb-connector. How do we convert Dataset data to hadoopRDD or DynamoDBItemWritable? Appreciate help. Not finding good documentation on emr-dynamodb-connector either.

```
//Read file
Dataset<Row> parquetFileDF = spark.read().parquet("/src/main/resources/account.parquet");

//Create hadoop RDD using above data ( Need to figure out this part)
JavaPairRDD<Text, DynamoDBItemWritable> hadoopRDD = sc.hadoopRDD(jobConf,
                DynamoDBInputFormat.class, Text.class, DynamoDBItemWritable.class);

//Save
hadoopRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf);

private static JobConf getDynamoDbJobConf (JavaSparkContext sc, String tableNameForWrite){
        final JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration());
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.servicename", "dynamodb");
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.input.tableName", tableNameForWrite);
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.endpoint", "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.regionid", "us-east-1");
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.proxy.hostname", "");
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.proxy.port", "");
        jobConf.set("mapred.output.format.class",
                "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat");
        jobConf.set("mapred.input.format.class",
                "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat");
        //jobConf.set("dynamodb.customAWSCredentialsProvider", profile);
        return jobConf;
    }
```

Comment: you have to call `parquetFileDF.rdd().map(` and therein create the tuples with `Text` and `DynamoDBItemWritable` - example code ist in the AWS blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-spark-sql-for-etl/

Comment: other groups also already created a custom DataSource for DynamoDB: https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb - maybe for other use-cases from your side interesting.

Comment: @UninformedUser  is it possible to give me Java example. Majority are Scala example. Our production code is in java. Searched the google but no luck.